# Liquibase create indexes with functions

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, indexing, liquibase

I have this database in postgresql which has this index:

```
CREATE INDEX fav_alias_lower_index ON fav_alias USING hash((LOWER(fav_alias)));
```

When I reversed engineered this database I got this liquibase changelog:

```
<changeSet author="jmartins (generated)" id="1410448831080-17">
   <createIndex indexName="workspace_favorite_alias_lower_case_index" tableName="workspace_favorite_alias" unique="false">
      <column name="lower((fava_alias)::text)"/>
   </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

This works fine when I apply an update on a PostgreSql database, however, it doesn't work on MySql for example. So my question is how can I make this index creation available for MySql, MSSQL and Oracle too, preserving the lowercasing of fava_alias?

Thanks

Comment: "*how can I make this index creation available for MySql, MSSQL*" - simple answer: you can't. In MySQL (and SQL Server) you would assign a case-insensitive collation for that column and create a regular index on it. For Oracle it should work the same if you remove the (unnecessary) `::text` cast

Answer (score 11):

If the function is available in your Database, you can use it in liquibase. There is a way to differentiate between different DBs using dbms attribute.

```
<changeSet author="jmartins (generated)" id="1410448831080-17">
   <createIndex indexName="workspace_favorite_alias_lower_case_index" tableName="workspace_favorite_alias" unique="false" dbms="postgresql">
      <column name="lower((fava_alias)::text)"/>
   </createIndex>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="jmartins (generated)" id="1410448831080-17">
   <createIndex indexName="workspace_favorite_alias_lower_case_index" tableName="workspace_favorite_alias" unique="false" dbms="oracle">
      <column name="lower(fava_alias)"/>
   </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: according to the recent documentation the `dbms` field doesn't exist in `createIndex` tag then we'd need to move it out to the `changeSet` tag.

https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/create-index.html

Comment: Strongly suggested to use the `computed` attribute